# Battleship game in java

Tags: java

I need help with a program I have to finish by this Saturday, it is really important, I actually have this code in spanish though. I am looking for a way to make a simple IA, here are my classes:

```
public class Game {
    private HumanPlayer[] players;

    public Game() {

        this.players = new HumanPlayer[]{
                new HumanPlayer(1),
                new HumanPlayer(2)
        };
    }

    public void start() {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        int len = players.length;
        HumanPlayer player = null;

        this.players[i].colocaBarcos();
        this.players[j].colocaBarcos2();

        while(players[0].getVidasRestantes() > 0 &&
                players[1].getVidasRestantes() > 0) {

            players[i++ % len].dispararA(players[j++ % len]);
            player = (players[0].getVidasRestantes() < players[1].getVidasRestantes()) ?
                    players[1] :
                    players[0];
        }

        System.out.printf("Enhorabuena Player %d, ganaste!",player.getId());
    }
}

    public class AguaField implements IGameField {
    private boolean fieldGolpeado = false;

    @Override
    public char getIcon() {
        return fieldGolpeado ? 'M' : '~';
    }

    @Override
    public Resultado dispararA() {
        fieldGolpeado = true;
        return Resultado.NO_GOLPE;
    }
}

    public class Barco {
    private final String nombre;
    private final int tamaño;
    private int vidas;

    public Barco(String nombre, int tamaño) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
        this.vidas = tamaño;
    }

    public void golpear() {
        if(vidas > 0) {
            System.out.printf("%nBuen golpe! El %s fue golpeado", nombre);
            vidas--;

        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("El barco fue destruido");
        }
    }

    public Resultado getEstado() {
        if(vidas == 0) {
            return Resultado.DESTRUIDO;
        } 
        else if(vidas < tamaño) {
            return Resultado.PARCIAL_GOLPE;
        } 
        else {
            return Resultado.NO_GOLPE;
        }
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getTamaño() {
        return tamaño;
    }
}

    public class BarcoField implements IGameField {
    private final Barco ship;

    public BarcoField(Barco ship) {
        this.ship = ship;
    }

    @Override
    public char getIcon() {
        char icon;
        Resultado barcoEstado = ship.getEstado();
        switch (barcoEstado) {
            case PARCIAL_GOLPE: icon = 'O';
                break;
            case DESTRUIDO: icon = 'O';
                break;
            case NO_GOLPE: icon = 'X';
                break;
            default: icon = ' ';
                break;
        }
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    public Resultado dispararA() {
        ship.golpear();
        return ship.getEstado();
    }
}

    public class BarcoTamaño {
    private BarcoTamaño() {
    }

    public static final int CARRIER = 6;
    public static final int BATTLESHIP = 4;
    public static final int CRUISER = 2;
    public static final int DESTROYER = 1;
}

    public class HumanPlayer implements IPlayer {
    private int totalVidas = 17;

    private int id;
    private Tablero tablero;
    private Tablero tablero2;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public HumanPlayer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tablero = new Tablero();
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Tablero getTablero() {
        return tablero;
    }

    @Override
    public void colocaBarcos() {
        System.out.printf("%n======== Player %d - Coloca tus barcos ========%n", id);
        tablero.colocaBarcosTablero();
    }
    public void colocaBarcos2() {
        System.out.printf("%n======== Player %d - Coloca tus barcos ========%n", id);
        tablero.colocaBarcosTablero2();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispararA(IPlayer opponent) {
        System.out.printf("%n Bien player %d - Introduce las coordenadas de tu ataque: ", id);

        boolean esPuntoValido = false;
        while(!esPuntoValido) {
            try {
                Point point = new Point(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
                int x = (int)point.getX() - 1;
                int y = (int)point.getY() - 1;

                Resultado resultado = ((HumanPlayer)opponent)
                        .getTablero()
                        .getField(x, y)
                        .dispararA();

                if(resultado == Resultado.PARCIAL_GOLPE ||  resultado == Resultado.DESTRUIDO) {
                    totalVidas--;
                }

                esPuntoValido = true;
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.printf(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getVidasRestantes() {
        return totalVidas;
    }


}

    public interface IGameField {
    char getIcon();
    Resultado dispararA();
}

    public interface IPlayer {
    void colocaBarcos();
    void dispararA(IPlayer opponent);
    int getVidasRestantes();
}

    public enum Resultado {
    NO_GOLPE,
    PARCIAL_GOLPE,
    DESTRUIDO
}

    public class Tablero {
    private static final char AGUA = '~';
    private static final int TABLERO_SIZE = 10;
    private static final char[] TABLERO_LETRAS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
    private static final String HORIZONTAL = "H";
    private static final String VERTICAL = "V";
    private static final String HORIZONTAL2 = "h";
    private static final String VERTICAL2 = "v";

    private Scanner scanner;
    private IGameField[][] tablero;
    private static final Barco[] barcos;

    static {
        barcos = new Barco[]{
            new Barco("Carrier", BarcoTamaño.CARRIER),
            new Barco("Battleship1", BarcoTamaño.BATTLESHIP),
            new Barco("Battleship2", BarcoTamaño.BATTLESHIP),
            new Barco("Cruiser1", BarcoTamaño.CRUISER),
            new Barco("Cruiser2", BarcoTamaño.CRUISER),
            new Barco("Cruiser3", BarcoTamaño.CRUISER),
            new Barco("Destroyer", BarcoTamaño.DESTROYER),
            new Barco("Destroyer", BarcoTamaño.DESTROYER),
            new Barco("Destroyer", BarcoTamaño.DESTROYER),
            new Barco("Destroyer", BarcoTamaño.DESTROYER)
        };

    }
    public void escogerBarco(){
        System.out.println("Que barco quieres introducir? ");
        String barcoEscogido = scanner.nextLine();
        if (barcoEscogido == "Carrier"){
            new Barco("Carrier", BarcoTamaño.CARRIER);

        }
    }

    public Tablero() {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.tablero = new IGameField[TABLERO_SIZE][TABLERO_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < TABLERO_SIZE; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < TABLERO_SIZE; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new AguaField();
            }
        }

    }

    public void colocaBarcosTablero() {
        for(Barco ship : barcos) {
            boolean horizontal = preguntaDireccionValida();
            Point puntoInicio = preguntaPuntoInicio(ship, horizontal);
            colocaBarcoValido(ship, puntoInicio, horizontal);

            printTablero();
        }
    }
    public void colocaBarcosTablero2() {
        for(Barco ship2 : barcos) {
            boolean horizontal2 = preguntaDireccionValida2();
            Point puntoInicio2 = preguntaPuntoInicio2(ship2, horizontal2);
            colocaBarcoValido(ship2, puntoInicio2, horizontal2);

            printTablero();
        }
    }

    public IGameField getField(int x, int y) {
        if(!dentroTablero(x, y)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fuera del trablero - intenta de nuevo: ");
        }
        return tablero[y][x];
    }

    public void printTablero() {
        System.out.print("\t");

        for(int i = 0; i < TABLERO_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print(TABLERO_LETRAS[i] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i < TABLERO_SIZE; i++) {
           System.out.print((i+1) + "\t"); 
           for(int j = 0; j < TABLERO_SIZE; j++) {
                System.out.print(tablero[i][j].getIcon() + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private boolean preguntaDireccionValida() {
        System.out.printf("%nQuieres introducir el barco horizontalmente (H) o verticalmente (V)?");
        String direccion;
        do {
            direccion = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        }while (!HORIZONTAL.equals(direccion) && !VERTICAL.equals(direccion));

        return HORIZONTAL.equals(direccion);
    }
    private boolean preguntaDireccionValida2() {
        System.out.printf("%nQuieres introducir el barco horizontalmente (H) o verticalmente (V)?");
        String direccion = "HV";
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        do {
            direccion.charAt(aleatorio.nextInt(direccion.length()));
        }while (!HORIZONTAL2.equals(direccion) && !VERTICAL2.equals(direccion));

        return HORIZONTAL.equals(direccion);
    }

    private Point preguntaPuntoInicio(Barco ship, boolean horizontal) {
        Point from;
        do{
            System.out.printf("%nIntroduce la posicion de %s (tamaño  %d): ", ship.getNombre(), ship.getTamaño());
            from = new Point(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        }while(!esPuntoInicioValido(from, ship.getTamaño(), horizontal));

        return from;
    }
    private Point preguntaPuntoInicio2(Barco ship, boolean horizontal) {
        Random random2 = new Random();
        Point from2;
        do{
            from2 = new Point(random2.nextInt(10), random2.nextInt(10));
        }while(!esPuntoInicioValido(from2, ship.getTamaño(), horizontal));

        return from2;
    }

    private boolean esPuntoInicioValido(Point from, int longitud, boolean horizontal) {
        int xDiff = 0;
        int yDiff = 0;
        if(horizontal) {
            xDiff = 1;
        }
        else {
            yDiff = 1;
        }

        int x = (int)from.getX() - 1;
        int y = (int)from.getY() - 1;
        if(!dentroTablero(x, y) || (!dentroTablero(x + longitud,y) && horizontal) || (!dentroTablero(x, y + longitud) && !horizontal)){
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            if(tablero[(int)from.getY() + i *yDiff - 1]
                    [(int)from.getX() + i *xDiff - 1].getIcon() != AGUA){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean dentroTablero(int x, int y){
        return x <= TABLERO_SIZE && x >= 0 && y <= TABLERO_SIZE && y >= 0;}

    private void colocaBarcoValido(Barco ship, Point puntoInicio, boolean horizontal) {
        int xDiff = 0;
        int yDiff = 0;
        if(horizontal) {
            xDiff = 1;
        } 
        else {
            yDiff = 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < ship.getTamaño() ; i++) {
            tablero[(int)puntoInicio.getY() + i*yDiff - 1]
            [(int)puntoInicio.getX()+ i*xDiff - 1] = new BarcoField(ship);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I got stuck and I don't know how to continue. Sorry for my bad English and if I placed this wrong, it is my first time using stackoverflow!

Comment: what exactly is it you're having trouble with?

Comment: Please guide us to understand your issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and especially read [ask]. As for your question: "I need help implementing a simple AI" is a little too broad. Where exactly are you stuck? Did you look for any tutorials on simple AI? One way to build a simple AI would be to a) randomly place the ships according to the rules (i.e. if a random position and orientation violates the rules try again) and b) randomly pick a free cell to place a bomb unless you had a hit in which case the AI would pick one of the adjacent free cells until it sinks the ship or hits an empty cell.

Comment: In general try to think of what an unexperienced human who just understood the rules would do or think about how you'd describe how to play to someone who doesn't know the game yet - write that down and replace all commands that include thinking (e.g. "think where you'd best place your ships") with doing the same thing randomly (e.g. "pick a random place for your ships") and as long as that randomnes adheres to the rules you have your basic AI which you'd then just have to code.

Comment: The thing is that, actually I tried to put a random in the code that place the ships. In other words, the computer is supposed to put the ships in the table but at the moment of starting the program, my part works but the cpu one stays on blank, it doesnt give anything and the program doesnt give any error so idk what happens!

Comment: Maybe it can be useful integrating libgdx  AI plugin https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai .                                                                
                                                                           

                Take a look.